# Spring : Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

For some reason, Spring isn't able to auto wire the Repo into the Service Class. I've gone through every SO thread that deals with similar problems and I couldn't solve my problem,

here is my code.

```
public interface WProcessItemDetailsRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<WProcessItemDetail, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<WProcessItemDetail>{

}
```

and the service class is

```
@Service("processItemDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class WProcessItemDetailsService implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2395733723021028217L;
    @Autowired
    WProcessItemDetailsRepo detailsRepo;

    public WProcessItemDetail save(WProcessItemDetail detail){
        return detailsRepo.save(detail);

    }
    public List<WProcessItemDetail> save(List<WProcessItemDetail> details){
        return (List<WProcessItemDetail>) detailsRepo.save(details);
    }

}
```

When I try to run the program, it fails with the following stack trace

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processItemDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: sa.tabukuni.gwsc.repo.WProcessItemDetailsRepo sa.tabukuni.gwsc.service.domain.WProcessItemDetailsService.detailsRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [sa.tabukuni.gwsc.repo.WProcessItemDetailsRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: sa.tabukuni.gwsc.repo.WProcessItemDetailsRepo sa.tabukuni.gwsc.service.domain.WProcessItemDetailsService.detailsRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [sa.tabukuni.gwsc.repo.WProcessItemDetailsRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [sa.tabukuni.gwsc.repo.WProcessItemDetailsRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1009)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Did you enable the jpa repositories with `@EnableJpaRepositories`? If so, add your configurations and also, add more details about your project structure

Comment: Have you either defined a component-scan to pick up the Spring Components to be registered or individually defined the beans?

Comment: I've just figured it out, this project is a part of multi modules system in which where using a unified hierarchy. An engineer changed the context file and set a new package for 'base-package' attribute in the <jpa:repositories> tag .

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the annotation for your interface:

```
@Repository
public interface WProcessItemDetailsRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<WProcessItemDetail, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<WProcessItemDetail> {}
```

Comment: '@Repository' is just enough here

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot, so that's what I entered.

Comment: When you're using Spring Data, using `@Repository` is not required. Using `RepositoryRestResource` isn't related to the question either.